# How can I avoid having to loop through and search through this data frame?

Tags: r, loops, search, dataframe

I have a 1 million row data frame that contains monthly water usage data (HCF) for various accounts from 2003-2010:

```
> head(LeakyAccts)
      ACCOUNT     Date HCF
1    10114488 Oct 2010  25
2    10114488 Sep 2007  24
3    10114488 Nov 2006  11
4    10114488 Jun 2008  18
5    10114488 Aug 2003   6
6    10114488 Jan 2008  30
```

Dates are `yearmon`'s. I want to know how much each account used every month compared to the same month in the previous year. So for each row, I'd like to find the difference between the usage in that month (`Date`) and the usage in the same month the previous year (`Date - 1`). In other words, I want this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(LeakyAccts)) {
  row <- which((LeakyAccts$ACCOUNT == LeakyAccts[i,]$UB_ACCT_NBR) & (LeakyAccts$Date == (LeakyAccts[i,]$Date - 1)))

  if (length(row) == 1) {   # no previous year for 2003
     LeakyAccts[i,]$Difference <- LeakyAccts[i,]$HCF - LeakyAccts[row,]$HCF
  }
}
```

Needless to say, this loop takes hours to run and seems very un-R-like. How can I avoid using an ugly for loop and speed up the computation? Is there perhaps a way to do this using an `apply` function or a `data.table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reconfigured your data a little to give a complete example:

```
library(zoo)
dat <- structure(list(ACCOUNT = c(10114488L, 10114488L, 10114488L, 20114488L, 20114488L, 20114488L), ate = structure(c(2010.75, 2009.75, 2008.75, 2008, 2007, 2006), class = "yearmon"), HCF = c(25L, 24L, 11L, 18L, 6L, 30L)), .Names = c("ACCOUNT", "Date", "HCF"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Which looks like:

```
   ACCOUNT     Date HCF
1 10114488 Oct 2010  25
2 10114488 Oct 2009  24
3 10114488 Oct 2008  11
4 20114488 Jan 2008  18
5 20114488 Jan 2007   6
6 20114488 Jan 2006  30
```

Since `yearmon` is essentially just a `numeric` value where a difference of `1` is a year's difference, you can get the matching differences from a year ago like:

```
dat$HCF - dat$HCF[match(dat$Date-1,dat$Date)]
#[1]   1  13  NA  12 -24  NA
```

...which you can also apply within each group like:

```
do.call(c,by(dat,dat$ACCOUNT,function(x) x$HCF - x$HCF[match(x$Date-1,x$Date)]))
#101144881 101144882 101144883 201144881 201144882 201144883 
#        1        13        NA        12       -24        NA
```

Or using `data.table` like:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- as.data.table(dat)
dat[, Difference := HCF - HCF[match(Date-1,Date)], by=ACCOUNT]
dat

#    ACCOUNT     Date HCF Difference
#1: 10114488 Oct 2010  25          1
#2: 10114488 Oct 2009  24         13
#3: 10114488 Oct 2008  11         NA
#4: 20114488 Jan 2008  18         12
#5: 20114488 Jan 2007   6        -24
#6: 20114488 Jan 2006  30         NA
```

Comment: Thank you! Using `match` with a data table seems to be a very elegant way of doing it.